# how to add an image to my header in iText generated PDF?

Tags: java, itext

I'm using iText to generate a PDF.  I created a custom PdfPageEventHelper to add a header (and footer) to each page.

My problem is I don't know how to add the image so it is displayed in the "header box".  I only know how to add the image to the document content itself (if that makes sense).

Here's some code snippets ...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Rectangle headerBox = new Rectangle(36, 54, 559, 788);
  /* ... */
  Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 154, 54);
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILENAME));
  HeaderFooter event = new HeaderFooter();
  writer.setBoxSize("headerBox", headerBox);
  writer.setPageEvent(event);
  document.open();
  addContent();
  document.close();
}

static class HeaderFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {

  public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    Rectangle rect = writer.getBoxSize("headerBox");
    // add header text
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
      Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase("Hello", fontHeader1),
      rect.getLeft(), rect.getTop(), 0);

    // add header image
    try {
      Image img = Image.getInstance("c:/mylogo.PNG");
      img.scaleToFit(100,100);
      document.add(img);
    } catch (Exception x) {
      x.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

Any suggestions on the appropriate way to add the image to the header are greatly appreciated!!

Rob

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are making two major mistakes.

1. You are creating a new instance of the object for every new page. This will result in a bloated PDF as the image bytes will be added as many times as there as pages. Please create the `Image` object outside the `onEndPage()` method, and reuse it. This way, the image bytes will be added to the PDF only once.
2. As documented, the `Document` passed to the `onEndPage()` method as a parameter should be considered as a read-only parameter. It is forbidden to add content to it. It's a different object than the one you created with `new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 154, 54)`. In reality, it's an instance of a `PdfDocument` class created internally by the `PdfWriter` instance. To add an image, you need to get the `PdfContentByte` from the writer, and add the image using `addImage()`.

Errors like this can easily be avoided by reading the documentation. You can save plenty of time by reading my book [iText in Action](http://itextpdf.com/book/).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Very helpful!  Thanks.  I will spend more time with your book.  In the meantime, what you (and Denisk) suggested works, but it has a side-effect.  When I add the `img.setAbsolutePosition(35,742); writer.getDirectContent().addImage(img);` to put the image at the top of each page, all of my document content (except for the header) gets pushed to the second page.  The first page is blank.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  I can post a new stackoverflow question with detailed code if that helps.

Comment: @RobertHume Posting a new question is the way to go

Comment: @RobertHume my first guess would be that you're using onStartPage() instead of onEndPage(), but I should see more code...

Comment: @denisk: what was downvoted? To be sure, I upvoted the question and the answer.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie That's it!  onEndPage() instead of onStartPage() fixed it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Can you try

```
img.setAbsolutePosition(10, 10);
writer.getDirectContent().addImage(img);
```

instead of

```
document.add(img);
```

inside `onPageEnd`?

Comment: Thanks, very useful, at the end of the day Bruno's answer was more detailed and helpful so I had to "check" his -- I hope you understand!  Thanks again.

Comment: @RobertHume I totally agree with you on this one

Answer (score 0):

I've set abolute positions and alignment to the image (in this case I placed my image in the header)

```
    try {
        Image img = Image.getInstance("url/logo.png");
        img.scaleToFit(100,100);  
        img.setAbsolutePosition((rect.getLeft() + rect.getRight()) / 2 - 45, rect.getTop() - 50);
        img.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);          
        writer.getDirectContent().addImage(img);
      } catch (Exception x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
      }
```

I've also adjusted the the document margins in order to have delimited space in the header and footer of the document.

```
document.setMargins(20, 20, 100, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution to add image at the top of the page. We can do it by positing image to the top also. it may fix your requirement

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, DocumentException {
      Document document = new Document();
        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                    new FileOutputStream("HelloWorld.pdf"));
            document.open();

            //
            // Scale the image to a certain percentage
            //
            String filename = "image.jpg";
            Image image = Image.getInstance(filename);
            image = Image.getInstance(filename);
            image.scalePercent(200f);
            image.setAbsolutePosition(0, (float) (PageSize.A4.getHeight() - 20.0));
            System.out.println(image.getScaledHeight());
            document.add(image);

            //
            // Scales the image so that it fits a certain width and
            // height
            //
            image.scaleToFit(100f, 200f);
            document.add(image);
            document.add(new Chunk("This is chunk 3. "));
            System.out.println("created");
        } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            document.close();
        }
}
```

}

Comment: The OP is talking about adding the image in a page event listener, and in such a listener you are not supposed to add anything directly via `document.add`, cf. e.g. @Bruno's answer, item 2. Thus, your solution does not apply in the situation at hand.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to convert your image to base64 and define it.

```
string base64Image = @"your_image_base64_code";
```

Then we converted the image into bytes

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Image);
iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBytes);
```

We need to adjust the position of the image on the page

```
 image.SetAbsolutePosition(positionX, positionY);//You must enter a float type value according to the x and y coordinates.
 image.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(40);//image height
 image.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(80); //image width           
 document.Add(image);
```

For more examples, you can visit [itextpdf](https://kb.itextpdf.com/it5kb/how-can-i-log-the-number-of-documents-bytes-i-ve-p) page

Comment: The op wanted an option to add the image in a page event. Thus, he shouldn't add it to some document object.